# bootstrap and npm - How do I import only the "reboot.scss" file in my project?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, bootstrap-4

I've started a simple playground project where I only have installed bootstrap (with `npm install bootstrap`), and the scss compiler package (with `node install nose-sass`).

I only need the `reboot.scss` code at the moment.
I would like to import it in my custom scss file and then start writing my bespoke scss code.

My scss file is in `/src/scss/style.scss`.
And I'm trying to import the bootstrap reboot file, which is `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss`.

In my `/src/scss/style.scss` I wrote:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot";
```

I need the reboot style from bootstrap. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you are correct.
Check this out: this is the documentation on how to do exactly what you mention.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#importing

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shouldn't have missed that from the documentation :D